# WPF. How to make a separator stretching to menu width?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menu

This may be is a dumb question... but I have not been able to find another question that answers it nor a post that could help me to achieve what I want.

I have the following XAML:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="Item1" />
    <Separator VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
    <MenuItem Header="Item2" />
</Menu>
```

In my real-life business case the header is more complex, having images and some other stuff.

The problem is that the above xaml is producing the following output:

[image]

As you can see, the separator is not stretching. It seems a very simple task to do... and yet I haven't found the solution.

What I have tried is to set a style to `ItemContainerStyle` where I give to `HorizontalContentAlignment` the value `Stretch` but it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default template includes a margin. You can remove it by defining your own custom template:

```
<Separator>
    <Separator.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}" Margin="0"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Separator.Template>
</Separator>
```

The default one looks like this on Windows 8 and later, i.e. the `Border` element has a hard-coded left-margin of `30` DIP:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

If your `Menu` includes several separators, you could use an implicit `Style`:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}" 
                                Margin="0"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="Item1" />
    <Separator />
    <MenuItem Header="Item2" />
    <Separator />
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just made it using a grid instead of a stack panel. I hope this works for you!

```xml
<Menu >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <MenuItem Header="Item1" />
        <Separator Grid.Row="1" />
        <MenuItem Grid.Row="2" Header="Item2" />
    </Grid>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked, although it seems a little hacky. I  am accepting the answer related with modifying Separator template because it looks more accurate for me. Although your answer certainly works but fails if you are binding to an items source, where you can not hardcode RowDefinitions